# Spark job hanging for 12 minutes after it finishes

Tags: apache-spark

I'm executing a spark job on a single executor in a standalone mode that runs as expected but it gets always stuck at the end for 12 minutes. Both the executor and driver docker containers are basically idling for that period of time. Here you can see the job and the logs :

https://gist.github.com/l15k4/25588d35a6c786b4ade514739c0195ee

I'm printing out the Stats which happens 12 minutes after the job finishes based on what I can see in WebUI ... Any idea what might be the cause?

It takes 20 minutes instead of 8...

After those initial 8 minutes, `nload` shows minimal upload/download traffic and `top` shows a minimal 3-5% CPU load in the driver container. Apart from that, everything else idles...

Comment: I'm not using Amazon S3 but I've heard about such issues on occassion and also read about it. Have a look at this article: https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/the-bleeding-edge-spark-parquet-and-s3/. It describes similar delays at the end of the job that can be solved by using DataBrick's DirectOutputCommitter (which circumvents the writing to a temp directory first, then copying after the job is done). Hope this might help you :)

Comment: Thanks PermaFrost, I just discovered extreme amount of http requests from the driver... It is really caused by inefficient merging of those temporary files on s3.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that those extra 12 minutes is spent on merging hadoop `_temporary` files on s3 to the target files. It is very inefficient as both download and upload don't perform better than 3 MBits/s even though downloading input files from s3 performs 70 Mbit/s.

In other words`rdd.saveAsHadoopFile("s3a:// ...)` is extremely inefficient and should be used really only for low volumes of data ...